# Как получить из десятичной дроби минимальное значение с тем же количеством знаков после запятой?

Tags: javascript

Например, есть числа

```
0.0034
0.5
0.000789
```

нужно из них получить

```
0.0001
0.1
0.000001
```

Comment: Что-то какой-то шквал безумных вопросов про числа с плавающей точкой в которых нет никакого понимания как они устроены…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function convert(num) {
  return 1 / 10 ** (num.toString().length - 2);
}

console.log(convert(0.0034));
console.log(convert(0.5));
console.log(convert(0.000789));
```